# How to access a service inside a linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, couchdb

I've recently installed linux using Sun's VirtualBox. I was wanting to play around with CouchDB, so I installed it onto the linux vm and have it up and running. Now, how do I get my host (Win7) to access the CouchDB database?

I did an ipconfig and it gave me what I'm assuming to be the vm's ip address as 192.168.56.1, as the ping times are less than 1ms. I tried accessing CouchDB with 192.168.56.1:5984 and it gives me nothing. Is there something else I have to do with CouchDB, linux, VirtualBox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check your host VM's IP and see if it's in the same network as the VM. If not, I'd suggest you set up your VM to use bridged, rather than NAT, networking. That way it'll appear to be just another client on your network without indirection.

Getting virtualbox's NAT network to be visible on your network is a layer of indirection that can be a headache to configure properly. A working bridging network configuration should clear that up a bit.

Comment: I went and changed it to bridged, and indeed my host can see my vm as a computer on my network. But I still can't access CouchDB from the host. I've went and changed the firewall to allow all traffic to port 5984 on the linux vm, but it still doesn't work? Any more ideas?

Comment: First thing I'd do is get rid of complication to test it. Drop your firewall on the Windows computer and VM system, if you have them both on. Drop completely, then see if you can access it. Next check from the host to VM that you can see anything on that port with a port scanner. Then check on the Linux system that something is running at that port (netstat is your friend). Then check to see if there is a setting in couchdb that prevents IP's other than localhost from connecting.

Comment: Hmmm, weird. Just had to restart the vm. Now everthing works. Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure CouchDB is listening on the VM's public IP address.  By default CouchDB is bound to localhost only.

Comment: Do you mean change the binding address to 0.0.0.0? If that's what you meant, then I did that already.

Answer (score 0):

PortQueryUI is a good Windows tool (like *nix NMAP) to see if another box is listening on a port.